# textarea breaks words and doesn't make new lines

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with textarea of phpBB forum. When users type in some content in some cases the line doesn't break, so the line continues without breaking to new line. In my case when I type content the words itself break for a new line.

for example, "machine" will be broken to "mach".. starting from the new line .. "ine" and I know that if there's no enough space for a word it should be moved to the new line.

I tried almost everything that I searched on the internet. Could someone let me know how to override every property and set textarea to the default, proper settings?

**UPDATE:**

here's HTML:

```
<div id="message-box">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="76" tabindex="4" onselect="storeCaret(this);" onclick="storeCaret(this);" onkeyup="storeCaret(this);" onfocus="initInsertions();" class="inputbox"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here's CSS:

```
#message-box textarea.inputbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    resize: none;
}

#message-box textarea {
    color: #333333;
}

textarea.inputbox {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jsfiddle and etc)

Comment: @mrGott please be more specific about your question, also provide your code

Comment: Hmm.. have you checked your CSS that may override your textarea styles? you might wanna check the `word-wrap:break-word`

Comment: I did check everything, there's only white-space:normal and it still messes up

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS, try

```
textarea{
  word-break : normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank for attention but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @mrGott, I guess you are really frustrated with this problem. I just installed a phpbb version on my localhost to help you out. As i see, the words doesn't break into two lines! Can you tell me exactly which "textarea" gives you this problem?